# Tool to slice LED stripe lengthwise

Tags: led, tools, cutting

For a light setup, I need to use a particular model of led stripes.
Unfortunately, the stripe with the LED model I need has a width of 12mm (and is globally only available in that width), the mounting I need to use can fit only 10mm.

From an electronics point of view, I can safely cut 2mm off the stripe lengthwise, however this needs to be done precisely and must not vary (2.5mm would be too much).

What tool could I use to efficiently do this? I need to cut ~10-15m of LED stripes.

Edit: The stripe is not enclosed, it is the plain PCB-only type.

Edit 2: The stripe is flexible, with one centered 5050 LED, the cut needs to be done on one side.

Comment: Why do you need that exact "model", perhaps if you explained your project in detail someone may have an alternative solution. Can the model in question be cut in half without rendering it useless?

Comment: Are these the silicone encased outdoor ones, or not? Any flexibility available in what you're mounting it on?

Comment: @AlaskaMan As mentioned above, it can be cut safely. I didn't mention the model, as from an electronic point of view, it is my only option

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Unfortunately, I have no flexibility in both the stripe and the mounting. The mounting has been installed to a wall permanently and cannot be swapped for a different model anymore.

Comment: @user5626466  - OK,  Given the limited info we have on the strip in question the only advise to  be given is  a razor knife and a straight edge. Can you do it as precisely as you need,  we can not answer that as we do  not know how the LED's you want to  use are made.  *Are there two LED's side by side? Is there one in the middle of the strip requiring that both sides need to be trimmed in order to meet your requirements*.  **You have not provided enough info for us to answer your question**.

Comment: make a jig with a 12 mm wide channel and two protruding blades

Comment: @jsotola you might have the same idea I did - feel free to edit and extent the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the LED strip is truely unobtainable in 10mm, then I'd be surprised.  Try checking other sources, like ebay and aliexpress etc.

---

If I was really stuck, then I would make a cutting block similar to those used to spiral-cut PET bottles into long strips.

[image: From https://www.instructables.com/Portable-Device-to-Turn-Plastic-Bottles-Into-Rope/]

You would want two razor blades mounted parallel and vertical, and a 12mm slot to guide the 12mm strip in straight.

```
-------------========= 1 mm waste strip
|   12mm     <--------------  10mm wide LED strip from the middle
|   wide                        This line is the 10mm output strip
|   LED      <--------------  Pull to the right by hand
-------------========= 1 mm waste strip
             .
             .
         Two razor blades in plan view, sharp edges point to the left.
```

Comment: this would probably work well for flexible LED strips, but the slitter would need a slot that's wider in some places to allow the bulky LEDs to pass through.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a fiberglass printed circuit (FR4) use a tile saw, the diamond grit rimmed blade cuts the the fibreglass like a hot knife through butter, and the fence on the saw will allow you to set your desired  width precisely.

If it's a flexible printed circuit board (polyimide) just use a gauge to mark it and then trim it with scissors.

Comment: Yeah, you want carbide or diamond tooling for any serious work on FR4 -- it'll dull lesser materials in no time flat

Comment: All we know about the OP‘s product is that it is an LED light strip. We have no idea what it is made out of and the OP has failed to answer questions regarding what it is made of.

Comment: Very true, @AlaskaMan, and your point is well made. This _does_ provide an answer to 2 options. (Not up enough on PCBs to know how many options may need to be addressed.) It would be nice if the OP would come back to address the questions asked of him.